# why does not my wp_query work?

Tags: wp-query

i want to display archive of posts for post type of `post`. so i created a `page template` and insert the following codes but i display nothing. **why? what should i do?**

```
<?php 
    $postnumcat = new wp_query (array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => '-1',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    ));
?>

<?php if($postnumcat->have_posts()) :
while($postnumcat->have_posts()) : $postnumcat->the_post(); ?>

    the_title();
    the_content();

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

even i putted `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` after `endwhile` like so:

```
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

and even like so:

```
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

but it display nothing too :|

Comment: Is this your actual code?  You don't have any "loop elements" to output

Comment: Do yo uneed this custom loop? WordPress has archives for every post type by default

Comment: @rudtek yes it is actual but instead of "loop element" you can consider `the_title()`. there is not any issue with that part

Comment: @kero even for post? how can i display the posts of default post type (post)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here, starting with the first part:

```
<?php 
    $postnumcat = new wp_query (array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => '-1',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    ));
```

Firstly, `wp_query` is misspelt, it's `WP_Query`

Some general notes too:

- Setting `posts_per_page` to `-1` is bad for performance. Even if you don't expect there to be many posts, set a super high number instead, but never say `-1` as that means unlimited, even if your server can't handle it. Use pagination if there are too many results
- Setting `cat` to `-1` tells WP to exclude the category with the term `-1`, which can be extremely slow and expensive. Avoid these kinds of queries at all costs

Then for some reason, there's a closing PHP tag, a space and newline, then an opening PHP tag, this will create unwanted whitespace:

```
?>

<?php if($postnumcat->have_posts()) :
```

Then we have the loop, which hasn't been formatted correctly, but notice **there is nothing inside the loop**, all you're going to get is a series of `<!-- Loop elements -->`. The code needs to actually display things

```
while($postnumcat->have_posts()) : $postnumcat->the_post(); ?>

<!-- Loop elements -->

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And finally, `wp_reset_query` is for use with `query_posts`, a function you should never use. Black list `wp_reset_query` and never use it, there is no reason for you to use it.

Instead,  lets go back to the original task:

> i want to display archive of posts for post type of post. so i created a page template and insert the following codes but i display nothing. why? what should i do?

WordPress already does this! By default this is your homepage ( `home.php`/`archive.php`/`index.php` ). But if you wanted to put this archive on a different page, using a page template then throwing away the main query and using your own is a terrible way to do it.

Imagine you sent your assistant off to buy you a coffee every morning. Except after she came back from a 40 minute round trip, you told them "No, I want a Hot Chocolate". Every morning you make them go out twice. Then the client complains your business is slow and doesn't perform well.

On top of that, you've just lost a lot of the benefits of WP, e.g. pagination will break, and you'll need to re-implement it to get it working again.

**Instead**, create a page called "Post Archive", go into settings, and under reading, set it as your posts page:

[image]

Then, create a `frontpage.php` and a `home.php` in your theme so that you can style them both. Use a normal, standard, main post loop in both.

#### For reference

This is a standard main loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

This is a custom post query:

```
$q = new WP_Query( [
    // args go here
]);
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

And this is what you're supposed to do if you want to modify which posts WordPress fetches, by telling it before it fetches them:

```
function my_home_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // only show posts from category 123 on the homepage
        $query->set( 'cat', '123' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category' );
```

And finally, put each thing on its own line, and indent them. There are a lot of free editors that will automatically do this for you, e.g. Sublime Text, VS Code, Atom, etc

Comment: Hi my friend, thanks for helping. in my theme, i have `index.php` that does not include the latest posts. i wanted to display all of post in one page. but you say i should create a `page template` without using `WP_Query` and just use a `loop`. then go into settings, and under reading. am i right? so by doing so, what is the slug of my post archive? consider that, when we add a `new post type` with a slug (e.g: book), by default, all the posts of that custom post type will be displayed in `yoursite.com/book` but there is not true for posts for `post type of post`